# Misuse of «which» by natives?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, sentence-construction

I recently noticed that some English natives tend to put which in inappropriate places, like here:
'I used to hang around their house which they always stayed with me, but it was okay'.
'Heʼd told me so, which I didnʼt even know if it was true', etc.
It is incorrect, right? And have any of you noticed that too?

The Internet doesnʼt seem to have a great deal of such examples, Iʼve found just one here [image: example]

Comment: No, I've never noticed that. I feel this question is off-topic, it is not about learning English.

Comment: How is that off topic? I want to understand if itʼs in fact a mistake, and how many people have encountered it in colloquial speech even if it is a mistake

Comment: Offside: You should say "native speakers" not "natives" by itself.

Comment: I have seen and heard that usage of 'which' in some US informal local-dialect speech.

Comment: I'm finding the first example difficult to parse, how can the speaker hang at someone's house if their friends are always guests at his place?

Comment: Thanks, as natives would refer to the native people, by the way I just was reading thru something and saw it also sometimes happens with «who» - https://ibb.co/NptT5bR

Comment: @Mari-LouA yeah I meant that they stayed with him at their house as if it was something unusual/unexpected for him, do not pay much attention though itʼs just an example

Comment: @eight_ball It's off-topic because a question here has to be on a point of learning English. Why someone you know said something incorrectly is not a point of learning English. Evidently, you already know it is incorrect.

Comment: How am I (or anyone else) supposed to say whether that example, which seems to be taken from real life, is representative of some British English speakers.  It looks bad English. The second example is OK

Comment: I'm not really sure what we can say about this except it just goes to show that not all English native speakers are particularly literate. That was just written by someone who, when they set off on the journey of that sentence hadn't considered how they would get to the end of it, so they just made something up in the hopes it would join the two ideas. It didn't, properly.

Comment: @Astralbee itʼs not just someone I know, there are many people out there who do that, but itʼs not easy to find a lot of these examples here on the Internet. Itʼs not off topic because itʼs related to language-learning, I want to know whether itʼs strictly informal and how many people have actually seen something like this or maybe even use it themself in order to know if itʼs more or less common than I think it is. And no, i didnʼt know it was incorrect, it was my assumption, thatʼs why I asked. --

Comment: -- Someone has stated up above that itʼs a dialect thing and when it comes to dialects a lot of things are 'incorrect' there.

Comment: I have seen that use of 'which' in direct British regional dialect speech in novels written in the 18th and 19th centuries.

Comment: @eight_ball - your `ibb` example isn't any type of dialect, it's barely functional literacy, by any measure. [Similar but worse than your three 'which' examples above.]

Comment: I've seen/heard/read this. Either in Australian English or "YouTube English" (-:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### The Likely Basis for the Usage

This may not seem like it answers the grammatical aspect of the question, but it is important to realize that native speakers of most any language often take shortcuts in their speech, slur their pronunciation, or use incorrect grammar--often deliberately, whether out of laziness, carelessness, or to make a point (for effect).

Young people, especially, often encounter a social dynamic that stigmatizes those whose grammar is too fastidious.  It is difficult to make friends when others perceive one's speech to put their own unscholarly language in a bad light.  For this reason, they may deliberately use incorrect grammar, as a matter of habit.

In the specific case of the use of "which" highlighted in the question, it may be serving as something of a catch-all word, similar to the use of "like" in the recent past in some circles where nearly every fifth word might be "like."  The "which" in both of the example sentences could be reasonably swapped out for the word "and." This usage may be similar to a vocalized pause, such as "uh..." or "uhm..." because many will use "and" in such a fashion.  Substituting "which" would be a somewhat local usage, and would not be used by everyone.

### The Grammatical Aspect

This usage of "which" is not grammatically correct English, but it may very well be common in certain circles of native-English speakers.

Comment: thanks!!! appreciate the verbose response, yeah I think youʼre right about it being the like substitute

Answer (score 0):

This may be a dialect. I suspect, though, that what you're hearing is a common mistake in spoken language.

Taking your example, I'd guess that what you're hearing is this:

> I used to hang around their house, which... They always stayed with me, but it was okay.

If I'm correct, you're likely to hear a short pause after the word "which". This signifies that the speaker intended to complete the phrase begun with "which", but was not able to immediately construct the phrase that they were looking for. Instead, they compose a new sentence as if they had not said "which".

Comment: Hi! Iʼm not sure about that, Iʼve never heard that use of «which» with the pause after it, I looked on youglish and found this example: https://youtu.be/d3Jlv5GfOSw?t=14 (you did facebook live as well which I didnʼt even know it was going on)

#2: https://youtu.be/jmyytbNxiPM?t=2988 (somebody found my telephone number from my office, which I didnʼt even know I had a phone number in it)

Comment: I think the first example is mis-transcribed, and has an "it" that was not in the spoken sentence. Because of that, I think that the first example is actually a grammatical use of "which" to begin a relative clause.

The second example seems to be a case where the speaker realized they had made a mistake later on in the sentence. Note the long pause after she says "phone number". The speaker also makes numerous other grammar mistakes in that video, which is common for someone who is not used to public speaking.

Comment: Well, what about everyone else? Iʼve heard lots of people do that, and it didnʼt have any pause, Iʼm leaning more toward it being a dialect thing. Btw I hear him clearly saying «it» in the first video

Comment: That may be the case. While I've heard people use which in this manner fairly often, it isn't necessarily what you're hearing. If this is a dialect, I'd be curious to know what the demographic is. I do have to disagree with you on the "it"; I am hearing it very clearly as "which I didn't even know was going on".

Comment: He didnʼt pronounce the t thatʼs all, why would he pronounce «I didnʼt even know-ee-was going on» if he didnʼt put «it» in there

Comment: I have no clue about the demographic, I certainly heard it in the southern US, but those videos donʼt seem to be from there, and another guy has said he saw it in the old british novels of the 18/19th centuries